# Install Apache Cassandra 3.1 on CentoOS 7

Tags: cassandra, centos

I'm not familiar with Linux and I need to install Apache Cassandra 3.1 on CentOS 7. I found a guide for Debian. Is there any guide for CentOS?

http://cassandra.apache.org/download/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could install it by following the steps in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/cassandra_installation.html.

Comment: `The requested URL /cassandra/cassandra_installation.html was not found on this server.` : Please check the link above.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.